# Cómo pronuncio la r suave?

Tags: pronunciación

Disclaimer: Hablo español, el español es mí lengua materna así que por favor no me digan que se pronuncia como la tt en "butter".

Nunca pude pronunciarla creo yo, y cuando intento pronunciarla suena como una "d" (no como una l u otra letra, siempre como una d)

Para pronunciarla me han dicho que tengo que tocar la "arruga palativa" (que se supone que es justo atrás de los dientes) con la punta de lengua, pero no me fue de mucha ayuda. También intenté hacer contacto con la lengua más atrás, pero no me funcionó tampoco.

Si alguien me puede explicar paso a paso como pronunciarla le agradecería mucho

Comment: Con el mayor de los respectos, te aconsejaría consultar a una fonoaudióloga. Es el único profesional que puede enseñarte a producir algún sonido que te cueste pronunciar. Es muy útil que sea en vivo y en directo. No creo que una descripción verbal del mecanismo de producción del sonido sea de ayuda.

Comment: También te puede ser de ayuda algún video donde veas cómo se posiciona la lengua hasta obtener el sonido. Lo bueno de la fonoaudióloga es que te da ejercicios hasta perfeccionar la pronunciación.

Comment: ¿ Se trata de la r o de la doble t en inglés?

Comment: Porqué hace referencia a palabras en inglés?

Comment: solo escuchando se entendería el escenario descrito.

Answer (score 2):

Mi hija tiene problemas con la r suave y la r fuerte, lo que se conoce en general como dislalia y en particular como rotacismo.

Como comentaban varios, lo más adecuado es consultar a un fonoaudiólogo aunque esto por supuesto puede tener un costo más o menos elevado. El profesional puede determinar si es un problema funcional u orgánico. En el segundo caso es posible que se requiera algún tipo de intervención médica.

Si el problema es puramente funcional, como alternativa o para empezar a practicar se pueden buscar videos que explican de forma más completa de qué se trata la dificultad y qué ejercicios pueden ayudar a superarla. Nosotros encontramos este video que nos pareció de buena calidad y fácil de seguir:

[TERAPIA DE LA /R/Sesión 1. Reeducación /R/](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4H9_sxGPwqs)

Answer (score 1):

Para pronunciar la letra 'd' con la lengua produces un golpe en la parte de atrás de tus dientes, esto no es lo que queremos lograr para una 'r' suave.

Si es tu lengua materna y debido a que no lo mencionas, se supone puedes pronunciar la 'r' fuerte. Repite algunas veces ese sonido. Para describir mejor lo que está pasando, la lengua se encuentra haciendo una curva en la que la parte inferior de la lengua toca el techo de tu boca. Después de eso llegar a la posición, vibramos la lengua produciendo sonido cuando la lengua toca el techo de la boca.

La 'r' suave es más sencilla. La posición es la misma, pero en el caso de la 'r' suave, no tienes que hacer vibrar la lengua. Un sólo golpe rápido al techo de la boca es suficiente para producir el sonido. De hecho es una consonante bastante rápida de pronunciar, comparada contra nuestras demás consonantes.

También la diferencia con la 'L', es que la 'L' también utiliza el techo de la boca para producir el sonido, pero esto lo produce sin curvear la lengua.

Comment: What are we even talking about? The r in butter, the tt in butter, the d in bud. ¿De qué se trata la pergunta?

Comment: How to pronounce the 'r' sound in spanish coming from a native speaker that doesn't know how to. The soft 'r' sound as in 'paradero'.

Comment: Oh, I see. Very, very confusing. They should give some examples. I guess she might be Puerto Rican....